# Internal Server Error

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, protocol-buffers

I am getting an unusual error while running my application, just wondering if anyone has come across this before. I am using google protocol buffers, my servlet takes a request and tries to process it, I have the following code:

```
InputStream s = request.getInputStream();
AdRequest adRequest  = AdRequest.parseFrom(s);
```

After executing the second line I get the error below in Myeclipse debugger:

Source not found for ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 310

I am using Jboss app server. I get a HTTP Status-Code 500: Internal Server Error.

Does anyone have any suggestions/thoughts?

Comment: If you comment out ALL lines of code in your doGet method, does it still throw the error? Who calls the internalDoFilter method? Sounds like something the servlet container is calling, hence itt might be something in your web app config (a filter, particularly) and not related to the AdRequest at all.

Comment: Stack trace?  I've gotten a 500: Internal Server Error before.  There are at least 2 ways that can happen.

Comment: I did comment all lines of code and ran my client program wihch calls the servlet this time its successful with Http Status 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out the problem. The protobuffers.jar file was not being included in my projects .war file, even though I had added the jar to my project MyEclipse was not including it. Upon following the path to the Jboss server and looking inside the .war I found out the jar was not there. After copying it over to Jboss/.../default/server/deploy/myproject.war/WEB-INF/lib directory the error has gone away and I am able to send a request to the servlet.

Thanks.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your jboss logs server//log/server.log (assuming you've not configured it to be somewhere else), and you'll get a better description of the problem.

The internal server error simply means that an unhandled exception is getting passed up the filter chain.